# Edit keys from a python object - getting TypeError: iteration over non-sequence

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I print out my variable

```
print myOptions
```

I get

```
 {'verbose': False,
'number': '1',
'asgMaxSize': '?dev = 2 | ?qa = 2 | ? prd = 8',
'availabilityZone': 'us-east-1a,us-east-1e',
'securityGroups': ['bouncebox-member', 'bouncebox-member'],
'\
    instanceType': '?dev =  m3.medium | ?qa = m3.medium | ?prd = m3.medium',
'runcommon': False,
'zone': 'inpwrd.net',
'bubblewrapp': False,
'healthCheckTarget': 'HTTP:8080/:NAME:/api/health-check',
'environment': 'dev',
'application': 'tint',
'nscustomerdata': None,
'ami': 'ami-8a5d81e2',
'userData': 'defaultUserData.txt',
'outputFile': None,
'description': 'tint - replacement thumbscraper stack',
'desiredCapacity': '1',
'securityPorts': 'httpPort8080,sshPort',
'instanceProfile': 'default-:ENV:1',
'elbListeners': 'http8080',
'name': 'tint',
'blockDeviceMap': 'Empty',
'instanceMonitoring': 'false',
'asgMinSize': '1',
'keyname': None,
'alarms': 'diskspace,memory,tint'}
```

(line breaks added for readability)

So it looks like a key/value pair to me. I want to iterate through it like this:

```
for key in myOptions:
    if key == "instanceProfile":
        myOptions.value = myOptions.value.replace(":ENV:", "dev")
```

But when I run the code I get `"TypeError: iteration over non-sequence"`

So, how do I determine what Type the object is and how can I walk through the key/value pair (dictionary?) that is there?

I am using python version 2.7.8 if that make a difference.

When I print out "print myOptions.**class**" I get "optparse.Values"

The construction of myOptions is

```
from optparse import OptionParser
_opt = OptionParser("%prog [options] configfiles...")

_opt.add_option("-v", "--verbose", ...)
_opt.add_option("-r", "--runcommon", ...)
.... a bunch of _opt.add_option

import shlex
def parse(filename, defaults):
    myopt, args = _opt.parse_args(shlex.split(open(filename).read()), defaults)
    return myopt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    myOptions, args = _opt.parse_args()
    myOptions = parse("default.ini", myOptions)
    for arg in args:
       myOptions = parse(arg, myOptions)

    myOptions, args = _opt.parse_args(values = myOptions)

    argConfigurationName = args[-1]
    if (myOptions.name == None):
        myOptions.name = argConfigurationName

    if myOptions.verbose == True:
        print "Configuration Variables"
        for name in _opt.defaults:
            print "\t", name, "=", getattr(myOptions, name)
```

Comment: Try `print type(myOptions)` and post the result

Comment: What happens when you type in `print type(myOptions)`? What do you see?  Is it a `dict` or a `str`?

Comment: It also looks like a JSON string.  Try doing `import json` `out = json.loads(myOptions)` if `myOptions` is a `str` so that you can convert the JSON object into a `dict`.

Comment: type comes back as "<type 'instance'>"

Comment: When I do a json.loads() it gives me this error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inPowered.py", line 124, in <module>
    out = json.loads(opt)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: "<type 'instance'>": That's *weird*... where did you get this object?

Comment: It looks like an old-style class - print myOptions.__class__ - and tell us what the class is.  It would also be extremely helpful if you told us where myOptions actually comes from, and how it is assigned.

Comment: Yeah definitely not a string.  OK.  Try doing: `import json` `out = json.loads(str(myOptions))` and see what you get.  I have no idea where this object came from or how you created it.  Can you please provide some insight onto its creation?

Comment: I modified the Question section to show how the object was created. Regarding the json.loads(),  I show the output for that in my 2nd comment above.